# How to Export Twice for Enzyme Testing Purposes Properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I want to test a react component by itself and not to use a mock store.
Let's say I have a component that is connected to a redux store and I export twice:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
 ...
}

export {MyComponent};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(injectIntl(MyComponent))
);
```

Then on my test file I will import the unconnected version:

```
import {MyComponent} from "./MyComponent"

const component  = shallow(<MyComponent />);
```

Is this the correct way to export components?  What do you use to do unit test on a connected component?  How much time does this save by not using a mock store for unit tests?  My tests are very time consuming because everyone is using mock store for all connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, although the syntax I'm used to would be `export class MyComponent extends Component {...}`.

In my opinion, connected components don't actually need unit tests, since you should trust that all the involved parts (`mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, `connect`) work out of the box. It's from an external library after all.

Neither `mapStateToProps` nor `mapDispatchToProps` should be overly complex, `mapStateToProps` delegates complicated stuff to selectors (which you can unit test independently), and `mapDispatchToProps` just puts redux actions in an object, or it does a bit of mapping (when the actions are dispatched with different arguments than the React component sees for example). In the latter case, you can export `mapDispatchToProps` and unit tests it in isolation by mocking only the dispatch function.

This is much less effort than putting together all the mocking for a real connected component that enzyme can `mount()`. However, sometimes this might be necessary, but I see this as more of an integration test.